# How to check if all dom-elements in an object containing a value

Tags: javascript, html

I saved all dom-elements in an object. I want that my Script is able to check every time when there is some input if all input fields are empty anymore. If yes, the button should still be disabled, otherwise the forward button is enabled and the user can click to the next page.

Ways like like using querySelectorAll input field etc. are working but I want that this is working with using the object.

The "areTruthy" variable is directly true if one input field is not empty anymore but it should only be true if all input fields are true. Where is my code wrong?

```
window.onload = () => {
  forward = document.getElementById("forward");
  input = {
    caseNumber: {
      month: document.getElementById("month"),
      year: document.getElementById("year"),
    },
    clientsInformation: {
      gender: document.getElementById("gender"),
      inpName: document.getElementById("inpName"),
    },
    adress: {
      street: document.getElementById("street"),
      houseNumber: document.getElementById("house-number"),
      postCode: document.getElementById("postCode"),
      city: document.getElementById("city"),
      receiver: document.getElementById("receiver"),
    },
  };
 

  addEventListener("input", () => {
    for (parts in input) {
      const areTruthy = Object.values(input[parts]).every((value) => value != "");
      if (areTruthy) {
        forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77,55,120)";
        forward.style.color = "white";
        forward.disabled = false;
        forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
        forward.addEventListener("click", () => {
          window.open("case.html");
        });
      } else {
        forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(191,191,191)";
        forward.style.color = "black";
        forward.disabled = true;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

```
<body>


  <h3>Fill in all fields</h3>
  <div id = "wrapper">

  <div id = "caseNumber">
    <label  id = "caseLabel"></label>
  <input id = "month" placeholder="Zahlenfolge">
  <input id = "year" placeholder = "Jahr">
</div>

<div id = "name">
  <label for = "name">Name</label>
  <select id = "gender">
    <option>Herr</option>
    <option>Frau</option>
  </select>
  <input id = "inpName" placeholder = "Name">
</div>

<div id = "adress">
  <label for = "adress">Adresse</label>
<div id = "adressWrapper1">
  <input placeholder = "Straße" id = "street" >
  <input placeholder = "Hausnummer" id = "house-number">
  <input placeholder = "Postleitzahl" id = "postCode" >
  </div>
  <div id = "adressWrapper2">
  <input placeholder = "Stadt" id = "city" >
  <input placeholder = "Adressant" id = "receiver" >
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class = "button-bar">
  <div class = "nav-inner" id = "backward"><a class = "nav-inner" href= "#http://127.0.0.1:5500/pages/client.html" ></a> <  Zurück</div>
  <div class = "nav-inner" id = "forward"><a href = "case.html"></a>  Weiter  ></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
.navbar {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgb(77, 55, 120);
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    gap: 4rem;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 45px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  
  .nav-text {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  #wrapper {
    margin-top: 10rem;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    display: sticky;
  }
  
  #caseNumber {
    display: block;
  }
  
  input::placeholder {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 19rem;
  }
  
  .button-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  
  .nav-inner {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 83px;
  }
  
  #backward {
    background-color: rgb(101, 93, 93);
    color: white;
  }
  
  #forward {
    background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
  }
  
  h3 {
    left: 20vh;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    
  }
  
  #caseNumber {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vh;
    margin-top: 6.5rem;
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  #name {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vh;
    margin-top: 12.5rem;
  }
  
  
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  input,
  select {
    width: 30vh;
    height: 5vh;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
  
  #adress {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vh;
    margin-top: 18.5rem;
    max-width: 40rem;
    display: block;
  
  }
  
  #adressWrapper1 {
  
    display: flex;
    gap:5vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    left: 18vh;
    position: absolute;
    top:0rem
  }
  
  #adressWrapper2 {
    display: flex;
    gap:5vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50vh;
   top:0rem
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking input **value**s. Also you are only checking `every` on child per parent object key, not on all children together so you need to lift `if` outside `for`

```
addEventListener("input", () => {
    let allFilled = true;
    for (parts in input) {
      const anyEmpty = Object.values(input[parts]).some(el => el.value == "");
      if (anyEmpty) {
        allFilled = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (allFilled) {
      forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(77,55,120)";
      forward.style.color = "white";
      forward.disabled = false;
      forward.style.transition = "1s ease";
      forward.addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.open("case.html");
      });
    } else {
      forward.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(191,191,191)";
      forward.style.color = "black";
      forward.disabled = true;
    }
  });
};
```

If you want to see what is exactly happening you can use this to log

```
  const anyEmpty = Object.values(input[parts]).some((el) => {
    console.log(el, el.value, el.value == "");
    return el.value == "";
  });
```